# Why do all nodes have to be linked to /rosout?

Tags: ros, rosout, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I was redoing [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams) tutorial where you get to run two turtlesims and one of them mimics the other. Well, exploring the rxgraph we get this:

[image: image description]

([link](https://i.imgur.com/OyZzD.png) for bigger resolution)

That's when I asked myself: why do all nodes have to be linked to /rosout? It doesn't make sense to me that /mimic is connected to it. What is the purpose for that?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11491/why-do-all-nodes-have-to-be-linked-to-/rosout?/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2011-10-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosout collects all data from the ROS_INFO...-style macros to display not only in the terminal but also in rxconsole. Nodes connect to it by default to be able to publish there.

If you are only concerned about the chaotic rxgraph output the "quiet" option will remove those.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4